# Different admin access in Active Admin for Rails application

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

In my Rails application I have different level admins with different access. How I can with adding some rules make for different admin types different access? Maybe exist module for this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ActiveAdmin` provides the ability to define an [`AuthorizationAdapter`](http://www.activeadmin.info/docs/13-authorization-adapter.html) for this type of access control.

I typically use [`CanCan`](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan), so I've found the `CanCan Adapter` they talk about on that page to be extremely useful. You just add the [CanCan Authorization Adapter](http://www.activeadmin.info/docs/13-authorization-adapter.html#using_the_cancan_adapter), then specify the permissions for the different roles in the `Ability` class, like normal.